# Return array of pixel values using Ruby and Mini Magick (or RMagick?)

Tags: ruby, image-processing, rmagick, minimagick

I'm trying to use mini_magick and ruby to get an array of all of the pixel values for an input image.

I plan on eventually working with that array to design my own codec for it, this is for a homework assignment.

Can anyone assist with the syntax for retrieving an array of these values? Or suggest that I use something other than mini_magick if necessary?

**Note:** I already have ImageMagick installed on my computer. I'm running Mac OSX Lion.

**Update**:
Because a user requested me to post the code I have already (even though it's not completely relevant)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mini_magick'

path = "/Users/ardavis/Pictures/Atlantis/Andy_and_the_Shuttle.jpg"
image = MiniMagick::Image.new(path)
```

**Update 2**:
Currently attempting to use RMagick, looking into the `export_pixels` function, not certain how it's used yet.
Thank you!

Comment: First rule of homework questions: show what you have already

Comment: Well, this question doesn't really work that way. I know how to do homework. This is a syntax question. I don't want anyone to tell me how to go through the array, how to compress and decompress, I'm asking for the syntax of mini_magick (or another suggested library) to attain the array of pixel data.

Comment: I added my code. So you see I have an 'image'. I need to get the pixel data from the image. All into a multidimensional array. Thoughts?

Comment: RMagick's [`get_pixels`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#get_pixels) sounds like what you're looking for, you'd have to rearrange the array a bit though.

Comment: @mu is too short, what's the best approach to using get_pixels and storing the numerical values into an array? I don't need all of the text that comes with it. I'll need to be able to iterate over this.

Comment: ^^ Apparently I can do `pixels = get_pixels(bla bla)` then later I can do... pixels[0].red.to_s etc. Thanks :) Mu, feel free to post an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: DON'T use RMAGICK under any circumstances. It is really old, unreliable and DOES NOT support new ImageMagick. Not a good idea anymore!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, [MiniMagick](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mini-magick) just wraps the command line tools so that's probably not the best choice for working with individual pixels.

[RMagick](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/) wraps the C libraries so pixel-level work should be a lot easier and faster. There is [`get_pixels`](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#get_pixels) in RMagick:

> Gets the pixels from the specified rectangle within the image.

That returns an array of [Pixel](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/struct.html#Pixel) objects and from there you can get the raw RGBA data and scale the numbers to whatever ranges works for you.

Comment: Thank you very much mu, I greatly appreciate your assistance. I was trying to figure out mini_magick forever. RMagick is definitely more useful :)